# android.app.SuperNotCalledException(error)

Tags: android

I am android newbie..I'm trying to test rss feed reader and I got this error message

> Caused by: android.app.SuperNotCalledException: Activity

**Error logcat** is here:

```
11-27 07:08:04.192: E/AndroidRuntime(1471): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
11-27 07:08:04.192: E/AndroidRuntime(1471): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
11-27 07:08:04.192: E/AndroidRuntime(1471):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:278)
11-27 07:08:04.192: E/AndroidRuntime(1471):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
11-27 07:08:04.192: E/AndroidRuntime(1471):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
11-27 07:08:04.192: E/AndroidRuntime(1471):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
11-27 07:08:04.192: E/AndroidRuntime(1471):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
11-27 07:08:04.192: E/AndroidRuntime(1471):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
11-27 07:08:04.192: E/AndroidRuntime(1471):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
11-27 07:08:04.192: E/AndroidRuntime(1471):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
11-27 07:08:04.192: E/AndroidRuntime(1471):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
11-27 07:08:04.192: E/AndroidRuntime(1471): Caused by: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
11-27 07:08:04.192: E/AndroidRuntime(1471):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:3939)
11-27 07:08:04.192: E/AndroidRuntime(1471):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.requestLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:701)
11-27 07:08:04.192: E/AndroidRuntime(1471):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:12555)
11-27 07:08:04.192: E/AndroidRuntime(1471):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:12555)
11-27 07:08:04.192: E/AndroidRuntime(1471):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:12555)
11-27 07:08:04.192: E/AndroidRuntime(1471):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:12555)
11-27 07:08:04.192: E/AndroidRuntime(1471):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:12555)
11-27 07:08:04.192: E/AndroidRuntime(1471):     at android.widget.AbsListView.requestLayout(AbsListView.java:1690)
11-27 07:08:04.192: E/AndroidRuntime(1471):     at android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(ListView.java:488)
11-27 07:08:04.192: E/AndroidRuntime(1471):     at com.example.testrss.ConnectToServer.doInBackground(ConnectToServer.java:78)
11-27 07:08:04.192: E/AndroidRuntime(1471):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
11-27 07:08:04.192: E/AndroidRuntime(1471):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
```

Here is **NPRNewsDetails.java** code:

```
package com.example.testrss;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.ArrayList;  
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;   
import org.w3c.dom.DOMException;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;   
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class NPRNewsDetails extends Activity {
    // a main category subject has already been selected by the user
    // (data <"urlCaption", "urlAddress"> comes in a bundle sent
    // by main, access web-feed and show corresponding headlines
    ArrayList<SingleNewsItem> newsList = new ArrayList<SingleNewsItem>();
    ArrayAdapter<String> aa;
    ListView myListView;
    String urlAddress = "";
    String urlCaption = "";
    SingleNewsItem selectedNewsItem;
    Context context = getApplication();
    ConnectToServer cNTS;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        myListView = (ListView) this.findViewById(R.id.myListView);
        // create a local Intent handler (needed to process input parameters)
        Intent myLocalIntent = getIntent();
        // grab the data bundle with all the pieces sent to us
        // it contains 1. url-address and 2. caption-text
        Bundle myBundle = myLocalIntent.getExtras();
        urlAddress = myBundle.getString("urlAddress");
        urlCaption = myBundle.getString("urlCaption");

        System.out.println("urlAddress ####" + urlAddress); // value from
                                                            // MainActivity
                                                            // http://www.npr.org/rss/rss.php?id=1007
        System.out.println("urlCaption####" + urlCaption); // Test RSS

        // top caption for this screen
        String todayStr = MainActivity.niceDate();
        this.setTitle("NPR -" + urlCaption + " \t" + todayStr);
        // clicking a line shows more about selected news item
        myListView = (ListView) this.findViewById(R.id.myListView);
        myListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> _av, View _v, int _index,
                    long _id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                System.out.println("item click index"+_index);

                selectedNewsItem = newsList.get(_index);



                showNiceDialogBox(selectedNewsItem, context);
            }
        });
    }// onCreate

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
         cNTS = new ConnectToServer(NPRNewsDetails.this,
                myListView, newsList);

         Log.i("onResum", "I'm Resume");
        cNTS.execute(urlAddress);

        Log.i("onResum", "I'm Resume");
    }





    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void showNiceDialogBox(SingleNewsItem selectedNewsItem,
            Context context) {
        // assemble a nice looking dialog box
        try {
            final Uri myLink = Uri.parse(selectedNewsItem.getLink());
            AlertDialog.Builder myBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            myBuilder
                    .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                    .setTitle(urlCaption)
                    .setMessage(
                            selectedNewsItem.getTitle() + "\n\n"
                                    + selectedNewsItem.getDescription() + "\n")
                    .setPositiveButton("Close", null)
                    .setNegativeButton("More", new OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichOne) {
                            // use native web browsing
                            Intent webIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                                    myLink);
                            startActivity(webIntent);
                        }
                    })// setNegativeButton
                    .create();
            myBuilder.show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }// showNiceDialogBox
}
```

this is **ConnectToServer.java** code:

```
package com.example.testrss;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
    import java.net.MalformedURLException;
    import java.net.URL;
    import java.net.URLConnection;
    import java.util.ArrayList;        
    import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
    import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
    import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
    import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
    import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;       
    import org.w3c.dom.DOMException;
    import org.w3c.dom.Document;
    import org.w3c.dom.Element;
    import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
    import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
    import org.xml.sax.XMLReader;       
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class ConnectToServer extends AsyncTask 
    {
        ListView myListView;
        Context context;
        ArrayList<SingleNewsItem> newsList = new ArrayList<SingleNewsItem>();

        public ConnectToServer(Context context, ListView myListView, ArrayList<SingleNewsItem> newsList)
        {
            this.context = context;
            this.myListView = myListView;
            this.newsList.addAll(newsList);
        }


        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) 
        {

            try 
            {
                String urlAddress = (String) params[0];
                URL url = new URL(urlAddress);
                URLConnection connection;
                connection = url.openConnection();
                HttpURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) connection;
                int responseCode = httpConnection.getResponseCode();
                if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                    InputStream in = httpConnection.getInputStream();
                    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory
                            .newInstance();
                    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
                    Document dom = db.parse(in);
                    Element docEle = dom.getDocumentElement();
                    // NodeListnl= docEle.getElementsByTagName("entry");
                    NodeList nl = docEle.getElementsByTagName("item");
                    if ((nl != null) && (nl.getLength() > 0)) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
                            dissectNode(nl, i);
                        }// for
                    }// if
                }// if
                int layoutID = R.layout.my_simple_list_item;
                ArrayAdapter<SingleNewsItem> aaNews = new ArrayAdapter<SingleNewsItem>(this.context, layoutID, newsList);
                myListView.setAdapter(aaNews);
            } 
            catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                System.out.println("Malformed error");
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("IO error");
                e.printStackTrace();

            } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
                System.out.println("Parser error");
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SAXException e) {
                System.out.println("SAX Error");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            return null;
        }

        public void dissectNode(NodeList nl, int i) {
            try {
                Element entry = (Element) nl.item(i);
                Element title = (Element) entry.getElementsByTagName("title").item(
                        0);
                Element description = (Element) entry.getElementsByTagName(
                        "description").item(0);
                Element pubDate = (Element) entry.getElementsByTagName("pubDate")
                        .item(0);
                Element link = (Element) entry.getElementsByTagName("link").item(0);
                String titleValue = title.getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
                String descriptionValue = description.getFirstChild()
                        .getNodeValue();
                String dateValue = pubDate.getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
                String linkValue = link.getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
                SingleNewsItem singleItem = new SingleNewsItem(dateValue,
                        titleValue, descriptionValue, linkValue);
                newsList.add(singleItem);
            } catch (DOMException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }// dissectNode

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Object result)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in your `onResume()` method you need to make sure you're calling `super.onResume()`

its usually good practice to make this the first line of your `onResume()` method, that way you know it will be called.

Comment: you mean @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            //call ConnectToServer.java super.onResume();
             cNTS = new ConnectToServer(NPRNewsDetails.this,
                    myListView, newsList);

            cNTS.execute(urlAddress);

        } [/code]

Comment: I think so, its a little hard to tell without formatting (comments don't format code), but as long as you're calling super.onResume(); somewhere in your onResume() method you won't get this exception :)

Comment: inserted super.onResume() in onResume()..I edited post...I added new edition of my code and error log..I think error concern with concurrent thread?

Comment: fixed! It's fine with by using onPostExecute() in ConnectToServer.java